# Will the frequency of a switching regulator have an effect on a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, voltage-regulator, frequency, switching-regulator

Will the switching frequency of my switching regulator have an effect on my microcontroller?

I'm trying to power this microcontroller [PIC32MZ0512EFE144-I/PH](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/PIC32MZ0512EFE144-I-PH/5323489) with a switching regulator from 24V to 3.3V. I'm currently looking at [this regulator](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/MC34063ECD-TR/1038914) but I'm not sure how if the frequency of this regulator will have an effect on my microcontroller. Do I need a higher frequency or lower frequency regulator to power a microcontroller?

Comment: Is it just me or neither of your links open (404)? Also, as long as you decouple well (caps at every power pin, close, may also want a bulk cap on the output of the IC within the specs), it should work fine. Many things are powered with switching regulators, unless there is significant voltage ripple. Another important point: these converters become very inefficient at low currents. The low end of the specification on many charts is 100mA for that IC (pulled its name from your broken link). MCU may use less. Just keep it in mind

Comment: @Ilya Works for me

Answer (score 2):

As Ilya mentioned above, as long as you have enough decoupling, you'll be ok. The switching frequency does not matter from a "can I power this microcontroller" perspective. What the switching frequency influences is the size of the components you can use (higher the frequency, smaller the sizes) and the efficiency (higher the frequency, higher the losses and hence, lower the efficiency). And of course, the switching frequency influences the type of noise you'll get which is less critical for digital stuff than for analog.

That regulator you linked to says it runs at 33kHz which sounds like a good selection for efficiency.